# How to apply imageView on touch scale animation in android?

Tags: java, android, android-animation, ontouchlistener, objectanimator

I want to apply some animation whenever user touch on button, like-

> 1. on touch/hover = scale down,
> 2. move finger out of the view bound = scale up to previous position,
> 3. on release/click = scale up to previous position

On touch animation is working perfectly but I am unable to figure out scale up animation to it's previous position when finger is being released. Also I am not too much familiar with Motion touch event, so please tell me which Motion Event will be appropriate to do this. Can anyone please help me. here is my code:

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        imageView.animate().scaleX(0.5f).scaleY(0.5f).start();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        imageView.animate().scaleX(2.0f).scaleY(2.0f).start();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        imageView.animate().scaleX(2.0f).scaleY(2.0f).start();

                        startActivity(new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class));
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

I have also tried with object animator, something like that:

```
private void scaleAnimation(View view) {
        ObjectAnimator scaleDownX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleX", 0.5f);
        ObjectAnimator scaleDownY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleY", 0.5f);
        scaleDownX.setDuration(150);
        scaleDownY.setDuration(150);
        //scaleDownX.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        //scaleDownY.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        //scaleDownX.setRepeatCount(1);
        //scaleDownY.setRepeatCount(1);

        animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        //animatorSet.play(scaleDownX).with(scaleDownY);
        animatorSet.playTogether(scaleDownX, scaleDownY);
        animatorSet.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright after a long experiment I have discovered the answer by myself. Here it is:

> After touch, if user move his finger then we need to cancel button click

```
boolean isMove;
// initialize
isMove = false;
```

> Set scale down and scale up animation

```
private void startScaleAnimation(View view) {
        ObjectAnimator scaleDownX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleX", 0.8f);
        ObjectAnimator scaleDownY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleY", 0.8f);
        scaleDownX.setDuration(150);
        scaleDownY.setDuration(150);

        scaleDownX.start();
        scaleDownY.start();
    }

    private void cancelScaleAnimation(View view) {
        ObjectAnimator scaleDownX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleX", 1.0f);
        ObjectAnimator scaleDownY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleY", 1.0f);
        scaleDownX.setDuration(150);
        scaleDownY.setDuration(150);

        scaleDownX.start();
        scaleDownY.start();
    }
```

> Now, apply this animation along with onTouch listener

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        startScaleAnimation(imageView);
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        cancelScaleAnimation(imageView);
                        isMove =true;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        cancelScaleAnimation(imageView);

                        if (!isMove){
                            isMove = false;
                            Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    startActivity(new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class));

                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_slide_left, R.anim.exit_slide_left);
                                    }

                                }
                            },150);
                        }else {
                            isMove = false;
                        }

                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```